# Why is window.opener.function printing out twice in React page?

Tags: reactjs, dom, window.open, react-dom, window.opener

I have a react functional component which returns a button to a page. This button when clicked, calls a function which opens a new window and sets a function inside the current window element.

```
export default function Authorizer_Spotify(props) {

  function someFunction() {
    let pop = window.open("http://localhost:3000/redirect", "", 'width=800,height=600');

    window.myCallback = () => {
      pop.close();
      console.log('hello');
    }
  }
  
   return (
    <div>
        <button variant="info" type="submit" onClick={someFunction}>
            click button
        </button>
    </div>
   );
}
```

This new window is a page set up by another functional component that calls the "myCallback()" function from the parent window by using:

```
export default function Redirect() {

    window.opener.myCallback();

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <p>Redirect Page</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

So when I type in the developer tools console "window.myCallback()", I should get a "hello". And when I press this button, I should also get a "hello".

For some reason, whenever I press the button, "hello" gets printed twice in the console and then  if I type window.myCallback() in the console, I get hello back but then it says undefined underneath it.

[image]

I'm not sure what about my code is making this run twice. The window.opener.myCallback() itself doesn't seem to be called twice but just the code inside of the function.

Comment: Please show the full implementation. It might be caused of "rerendering" or the way you call your `someFunction`.

Comment: @suther Okay I've updated it to show the full implementation